# Trying to configure spring-mvc to use <mvc:annotation-driven/> for @ControllerAdvice for GlobalExceptionHandeling in dispatcher-servlet.xml

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, exception, spring-4

> I need to use @ControllerAdvice for Global Exception Handling in my
>   application. For that i done these changes in my dispatcher    I am
>   getting Exception in configuring xmlns:mvc in dispatcher. :(
>
> I have tried the configuration with and without Version but in both
>   the cases it is not working.  Meanwhile I have not done any code
>   regarding @ControllerAdvice.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.3.xsd
        ">
    <mvc:annotation-driven/> 
    <context:annotation-config/>
.....
```

> ERROR msg i am getting:

```
2019-07-03 17:41:13 WARN  XmlWebApplicationContext  - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.OptionalValidatorFactoryBean#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.hibernate.validator.engine.ConfigurationImpl.getDefaultParameterNameProvider()Ljavax/validation/ParameterNameProvider;
2019-07-03 17:41:13 ERROR DispatcherServlet  - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.OptionalValidatorFactoryBean#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.hibernate.validator.engine.ConfigurationImpl.getDefaultParameterNameProvider()Ljavax/validation/ParameterNameProvider;
```